# Store a File in Android from a JAR File

Tags: android, api, jar, file-permissions

I am writing some backend interface code for an Android App. I would like to package up the backend api in a jar file and include it as a lib in the main app. (I have the same problem even it it's a library project).

One of the features of this api is to download a file from a remote server. I have a method which I pass the "root path" into the api.

```
public void storeRemoteFile(String rootPath)
```

The method starts a thread, and in the background grabs the file and stores it to the roothPath. I have no problems running this code in the Console, and the file gets downloaded to my PC. So calling this method in a class that lives in the jar file gives me a file permissions error.

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/adcard0/Android/data/com.myapp/files/temp.zip: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

Is there any way to give the api permissions to write the file? If not, are there any suggestions on how to allow the api jar to download the file, and pass it up the main app for storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure you have

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

In your Manifest.

Comment: It was so obvious I didn't think to look. I haven't been working in the app, just in the api. Thanks!